# for each *.pdf in a directory select specific pages and generate a new pdf for each

Tags: python

Just learning Python and trying to produce code that re-saves each pdf in a folder with only specific pages (same page numbers for each pdf e.g. the 1st and 3rd page) into a new folder.

Tried to follow some examples and came up with this

```
from PyPDF4 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from os import listdir
input_dir = 'C:/.../update/'
output_dir = 'C:/.../update_output/'

for x in listdir(input_dir):
    pdf_in=open(input_dir + x, 'rb')
    pdf_reader=PdfFileReader(pdf_in)
    output=PdfFileWriter()
    pages_to_keep = [0, 2]
    for i in pages_to_keep:
        p = pdf_in.getPage(i)
        output.addPage(p)
    with open(pdf_in+x, 'wb') as f:
            output.write(f)
```

Error AttributeError: '_io.BufferedReader' object has no attribute 'getPage'

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to operate on the PdfFileReader instead of on the open file.
You also need to write the output to something other than the open file.
Try instead:

```
for x in listdir(input_dir):
    pdf_in=open(input_dir + x, 'rb')
    pdf_reader=PdfFileReader(pdf_in)
    output=PdfFileWriter()
    pages_to_keep = [0, 2]
    for i in pages_to_keep:
        p = pdf_reader.getPage(i)
        #       ^^^^^^
        output.addPage(p)
    with open(x, 'wb') as f:
        #     ^
        output.write(f)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That worked perfectly... i had spent hours on this.

Comment: You're very welcome. Happy coding to you! And you could come to SO sooner next time :)